# java+JOGL, how to set transparancy to show objects in the scene instead of plain black when drawing a texture?

Tags: java, opengl, transparency, jogl, sprite

We are writing a simple 3D game as a project in a course we take at the university. (the assignment is for couples)
we have to use **JOGL**, so i gotta work with this API (solutions such as: *switch to higher level API such as java3D* won't be good for me...)
anyway, the game we decided to implemet is some sort of a 3D shooter.
(the code so far, which is forked from a previous assignment we made for the same course can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/mirzhcode/source/browse/?repo=cgex4 )
and now i'm trying to deal with "special effects".
more precisely, particles & sprites (for shooting, explosions, etc'...)
i came across an explanation regarding sprite emitters, which i want to implement: http://bit.ly/KrrPM4

i started out with what seemed to be the easy part. the shockwave ring, which is composed of a single rapidly growing sprite.
when i'm trying to draw the image i made, i get black background instead of the transparency i wanted.
the texture image is a transparent png file (so there's an alpha channel)
[image: shockwave png file with alpha transperancy]
and what i get from it is:
[image]
the code i used to generate this:

in `init()` method:

```
//loading textures
try {
    shockwave = TextureIO.newTexture(new File( "textures/shockwave_128X128.png" ),false);
} catch (GLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);
gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
gl.glClearDepth(1.0);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE);
gl.glHint(GL.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);
gl.glHint(GL.GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE OF CODE
//FOR REALISTIC COLORS. NOTE THAT ICC
//BUTTON WON'T CHANGE THE COLORS ANYMORE.

//gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHTING);

//two (soft) lights (red and blue) setup.
//each in an opposite corner of the room.
float color0[] = {1f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f};
float ambient0[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f};
float position0[] = {(float) (0.95*expansionFactor), (float) (0.95*expansionFactor), (float) (0.95*expansionFactor)};

float color1[] = {0f, 0f, 1f, 0.5f};
float ambient1[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f};
float position1[] = {(float) (0.95*expansionFactor), (float) (0.95*expansionFactor), (float) (0.95*expansionFactor)};

gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT, ambient0,1); 
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE,color0 , 1); 
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPECULAR, color0 , 1); 
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, position0, 1);

gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_AMBIENT, ambient1,1); 
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_DIFFUSE,color1 , 1); 
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_SPECULAR, color1 , 1); 
gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_POSITION, position1, 1);

gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT0);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT1);

start();
```

and also in `display()` method:

```
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
shockwave.bind();

gl.glColor4f(1f,1f,1f,1f);

gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3d(0.0-10, 0.2, 0.0-10);
gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); gl.glVertex3d(0.0+10, 0.2, 0.0-10);
gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3d(0.0+10, 0.2, 0.0+10);
gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); gl.glVertex3d(0.0-10, 0.2, 0.0+10);
gl.glEnd();
```

to sum it up, my question is how do i get the texture to use it's alpha channel,
and if it's not that simple, is there a library you might know i can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after digging a bit more, i realized what i needed to do.
apparantly, when you blend images with openGL, it's blended to the frame rendered so far.
so the order of drawing is important.
i rendered this image at the begining of the display method, and i should have put this at the end.
so anyway, if anyone wants to know how to draw transparent objects, make sure you draw them last.
in case there numeros transparent objects, you have to draw it in order. further away from the camera should be drawn first.
[image: after the fix]